# select more column not in group by using linq in c#

Tags: asp.net, linq

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(" ", con);

da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable t_eight = new DataTable("t_eight");
da.Fill(t_eight); //databale "t_eight" fill
    
//linq query
var query3 = (from a in t_eight.AsEnumerable() //t_eigth Databale
              group a by new
              { //Group by with condition
                  IdendityName = a.Field<String>("Idendity Name"),
                  ContactPersonName = a.Field<String>("Contact Person Name"),
                  CustomerName = a.Field<String>("Customer Name")
              }
              into g
              select new
              {
                  IdendinyName = g.Key.IdendityName,
                  ContactPersonName = g.Key.ContactPersonName,
                  CurtomerName = g.Key.CustomerName,
                  TotalBook = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Int32>("Total Book Quantity")
                      + x.Field<Int32>("Quatan Book Qty")
                      - x.Field<Int32>("Return Book Quality"))
              });

GridView1.DataSource = query3;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Datatable contains columns Identity Name, customer Name, customer Contact Name, Total Book Quantity, Return Book Quality, and Quatan Book Qty.

Group by contains three column Identity Name, customer Name, and customer Contact Name

New column in select statement Total Book contains ( total book quant+Quatan Book Qty-Return Book Quality). I want all columns in the gridview but the grid contains Identity Name, customer Name, customer Contact Name, and total book columns

How can I do this?

## Dataset table "t_eight"

[image: dataset table "t_eight"]

## Gridview missing column Quatan Book and Return Book

[image: gridview missing column Quatan Book and Return Book]

Comment: Can you please read your question and check if its clear to you?

Comment: what i do for answer

Comment: re-write question to be in clearer English without misspellings.

Comment: What columns are missing from the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you expect the additional fields to be identical once the rows are grouped, you just need to pick a random row from the group to get the values - the `First` row should work.

```
var query3 = (from a in t_eight.AsEnumerable()//t_eigth Databale

                      group a by new
                      {//Group by with condition
IdendityName = a.Field<String>("Idendity Name"),
ContactPersonName = a.Field<String>("Contact Person Name"),
CustomerName = a.Field<String>("Customer Name")
                      }
                          into g
                          select new {
                              g.Key.IdendityName,
                              g.Key.ContactPersonName,
                              g.Key.CustomerName,
                              ReturnBookQuality = g.First().Field<Int32>("Return Book Quality"),
                              QuatanBookQty = g.First().Field<Int32>("Quatan Book Qty"),
TotalBook = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Int32>("Total Book Quantity")
                                  + x.Field<Int32>("Quatan Book Qty") - x.Field<Int32>("Return Book Quality"))
                          }
              );
```

Note: I removed the redundant member names from the anonymous type, I don't see any reason to put them there.

Comment: Error come when i change the code                                                 Error 2 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnBookQuality' and no extension method 'ReturnBookQuality' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That part is copied literally from your example. Is your example working code?

Comment: yes my code is working. But two lines that you edit is not working                      g.First().ReturnBookQuality, g.First().QuatanBookQty. Please help me

Comment: but sir code is not working please give some more solution                              Sergey Berezovskiy , NetMage, Gert Arnold please provide some solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to see the totals of three columns besides the calculated `TotalBook` column. Here's how you can do that:

```
var query3 = (from a in t_eight.AsEnumerable()
              group a by new
              {
                  IdendityName = a.Field<String>("Idendity Name"),
                  ContactPersonName = a.Field<String>("Contact Person Name"),
                  CustomerName = a.Field<String>("Customer Name")
              }
              into g

              let tbq = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Int32>("Total Book Quantity"))
              let qbq = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Int32>("Quatan Book Qty"))
              let rbq = g.Sum(x => x.Field<Int32>("Return Book Quality"))

              select new
              {
                  IdendinyName = g.Key.IdendityName,
                  ContactPersonName = g.Key.ContactPersonName,
                  CurtomerName = g.Key.CustomerName,
                  TotalBookQuantity = tbq,
                  QuatanBookQuantity = qbq,
                  ReturnBookQuantity = rbq,
                  TotalBook = tbq + qbq - rbq
              });
```

The three `let` statements collect the individual sums per grouping, after which you can use the variables `tbq` etc. multiple times.